# dd a linux volume from windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, dd, partition-copy

I'm booting Lubuntu from Windows 7 by installing Grub in the linux partition itself (and not the MBR), dumping the first 512 bytes of the linux partition on a linux.bin file and then booting linux.bin from Windows bootloader.

There is a problem: every time that these 512B change with system updates (probably just when Grub is updated), if I don't dump the linux.bin file again linux won't boot anymore.

Whenever this happens I need to use a live linux to create linux.bin again and save the day.

I want to be able to do this from Windows, so that I don't need any live distro. 
I found dd for Windows at http://www.chrysocome.net/dd but the problem is that I don't see the linux volume with dd --list

I can only see it on the Windows Disk Manager but I don't know how I can refer to it.